# call the self object inside update_all in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a situation like, I have a product table which has a JSON field, I have to call a method to update that. So there are two approaches

```
 Product.all.each do |pr|
   pr.update_column(:boolean_tree, pr.change_boolean_tree)
 end
```

There is nothing wrong with this **apart from performance** . To improve the performance we can run **raw SQL** . Which will definitely works fine, but not in a rails way.

I was thinking is it possible to use **update_all** for this kind of situation. Any idea ?

Comment: There is no way to call a ruby method (`change_boolean_tree`) from SQL. You can precompute values of a large SQL query -- but this is easy to do for a bulk `INSERT INTO` but I believe requires a gigantic `CASE` statement for an `UPDATE`. I'd advise against the latter unless it's a one-time script. Further complicating this is the fact that the column is JSON data. If you can write an equivalent `change_boolean_tree` in raw SQL on JSON data then that's doable. As I see it, those are the two options given your data construction.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz yes i know this approach. was thinking if there is any way of doing it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Have you tried one of these two approaches? What was the result? The statements themselves are pretty easy to construct conceptually, they're just pretty crude and offer none of the standard Rails protections or conveniences so it becomes easy to screw something up.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you won't be able to use `update_all` unless you are trying to update all your records with the same content. When there are a lot of Products in the database the instruction `Product.all` would load all the records in memory before starting the update.

I would recommend using `find_in_batches` method from Activerecord ([see doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches)) to load the products in batches.

Comment: You can use `update_all` with different content if you write the SQL fragment: e.g. `Model.update_all("field1 = some_sql_function_on(field2)")`

Comment: In this case it seems that `change_boolean_tree` is a ruby function instead of a SQL function. would your commend work with ruby functions?

Comment: Nope, you'd have to write the ruby method as a SQL function to use this form. Pretty difficult given that `boolean_tree` is JSON data. The other option is to load in batches like you suggested, precompute updated values in ruby, then build a `CASE` statement on `products.id` using the precomputed values in the SQL fragment. Really, really bulky, but it would work.

Comment: @Bustikiller you can not call the ruby method unless values are same for all the columns.